# Word for "Squeezing a sponge full of water"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or words for the concept of squeezing a sponge full of water to get the water out? Or more generally squeezing any absorbing material out of its liquid?

The connotation I'm looking for is a word that could be used figuratively for that concept as well. For example, emptying our heart from emotions by crying a lot.

For example: It is good to * ones heart from times to times. This is just an example of how that word would be used.

Comment: One possible phrase is *"wring out"*.

Comment: or just "squeeze out the sponge".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That’s **[wringing out](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wring%20out)** a sponge:

> To wring out is to squeeze liquid from something by pressing or twisting it

Here’s an example of it being used figuratively:

> Plumbing morally complex depths with comedy and compassion, Jojo Moyes elevates the story of Lou and Will from what could have been a maudlin weepie into a tragic love story, with a catharsis that will **wring out your heart** and leave you feeling fearless. -- [Mari Malcolm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0718159047)